# Blazor WSAM JS error first time a page loads scripts not found in _content

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-jsinterop

So I have a Blazor WASM app and on a particular Page the when I navigate to in the first time I get an error with a package (BlazorPanzoom) but if I reload the page all works as designed.
I think the issue is that the JS package is not being loaded before the component it builds is being loaded.

Here are some details:

**The error encountered on first load**

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'blazorPanzoom.createPanzoomForReference' ('blazorPanzoom' was undefined).
> Error: Could not find 'blazorPanzoom.createPanzoomForReference' ('blazorPanzoom' was undefined).
> at https://localhost:7286/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:328
> at Array.forEach ()
> at a.findFunction (https://localhost:7286/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:296)
> at _ (https://localhost:7286/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:2437)
> at https://localhost:7286/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3325
> at new Promise ()
> at Object.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:7286/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3306)
> at Object.St [as invokeJSFromDotNet] (https://localhost:7286/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:59938)
> at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor (https://localhost:7286/_framework/dotnet.6.0.4.dckq00jdfr.js:1:195300)
> at wasm://wasm/00970c26:wasm-function[219]:0x1a0fb
> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'blazorPanzoom.createPanzoomForReference' ('blazorPanzoom' was undefined).
> Error: Could not find 'blazorPanzoom.createPanzoomForReference' ('blazorPanzoom' was undefined).

**_content after first load**

[image: _content after first load]

**_content after second load**

[image: _content after second load]

**Code Referenceing the component**

```
<div class="container">
    <ScrollableMap _map="@_map" _class="@mclass"></ScrollableMap>
    <NavigableMap _map="@_map" _class="@gclass"></NavigableMap>
    ........
</div>
```

**The component**

```
<Panzoom  WheelMode="WheelMode.ZoomWithWheel">
    <img @ref="@context.ElementReference" id="mappic" class="@_class w-100 img-fluid align-self-center align-middle d-block mx-auto" src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(_map.ImgImage)" alt="@_map.MapKey"/>
</Panzoom>
```

**Index.html**

```
<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="territory.mobi.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/assets/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<script defer src="/fontawesome/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="_content/Blazored.Modal/blazored-modal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xyz"></script>
```

.....

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script src="/js/site.js"></script>
<script src="/js/idb.js"></script>
<script src="/js/localTerritoryMobiStore.js"></script>
<script src="_content/BlazorPanzoom/panzoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="_content/BlazorPanzoom/blazorpanzoom.js"></script>
<script src="_content/BlazorGoogleMaps/objectManager.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclustererplus/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="_content/Blazored.Modal/blazored.modal.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<script src="_content/WYSIWYGTextEditor/quill-blot-formatter.min.js"></script>
<script src="_content/WYSIWYGTextEditor/BlazorQuill.js"></script>
<script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
<script>StartBlazor();</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your index.html?

Comment: Added indexd.html

Comment: Try putting `_framework/blazor.webassembly.js` as the last script

Comment: I have put it in the head, at the bottom of the body all with the same result. I cannot figure what triggers the _content to be loaded with the JS file on the second load.